# How to show chosen image in FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help, I have FileUpload control on my asp.net page and Image where I show image which is uploaded on server. What I want that Image show what I choose when I click on Browse in FileUpload control before I upload on server. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use some sort of Flash/Silverlight/Java control that can access the file system and show a thumbnail of the selected file. What you want is not possible otherwise, without uploading the file to the server first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must upload file to server asynch. before saving by user.